# AWS Lambda Athena getQueryResults With no results

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I'm trying to get the output of getQueryResults 
 using the below code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var athena = new AWS.Athena();

const DEBUG = process.env.DEBUG;
const GLOCA_ENVID = process.env.GLOCA_ENVID;
const GLOCA_AWS_ACCOUNTID = process.env.GLOCA_AWS_ACCOUNTID;
const GLOCA_AWS_REGION = process.env.GLOCA_AWS_REGION;

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

    athena.getQueryResults({
        QueryExecutionId: "a1b2c3d4-5678-90ab-cdef-EXAMPLE11111"
        },function(err,data){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log("Body: ", data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Below is the output:**

```
{
  UpdateCount: 0,
  ResultSet: { Rows: [ [Object] ], ResultSetMetadata: { ColumnInfo: [Array] } }
}
```

The output should look something like this:

```
{
    "ResultSet": {
        "Rows": [
            {
                "Data": [
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "date"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "location"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "browser"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "uri"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "status"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Data": [
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "2014-07-05"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "SFO4"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "Safari"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "/test-image-2.jpeg"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "200"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Data": [
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "2014-07-05"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "SFO4"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "IE"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "/test-image-2.jpeg"
                    },
                    {
                        "VarCharValue": "200"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "ResultSetMetadata": {
            "ColumnInfo": [
                {
                    "CatalogName": "hive",
                    "SchemaName": "",
                    "TableName": "",
                    "Name": "date",
                    "Label": "date",
                    "Type": "date",
                    "Precision": 0,
                    "Scale": 0,
                    "Nullable": "UNKNOWN",
                    "CaseSensitive": false
                },
                {
                    "CatalogName": "hive",
                    "SchemaName": "",
                    "TableName": "",
                    "Name": "location",
                    "Label": "location",
                    "Type": "varchar",
                    "Precision": 2147483647,
                "Data": [

                    "Scale": 0,
                    "Nullable": "UNKNOWN",
                    "CaseSensitive": true
                },
                {
                    "CatalogName": "hive",
                    "SchemaName": "",
                    "TableName": "",
                    "Name": "browser",
                    "Label": "browser",
                    "Type": "varchar",
                    "Precision": 2147483647,
                    "Scale": 0,
                    "Nullable": "UNKNOWN",
                    "CaseSensitive": true
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "UpdateCount": 0
}
```

The above output is an example output, but a similar outcome is what I'm expecting. When I run in AWS CLI:

```
aws athena --region "us-west-2" get-query-results --query-execution-id a1b2c3d4-5678-90ab-cdef-EXAMPLE11111
```

I get the expected output, so I'm unable to understand why I can't get the same result via lambda.

Thank you so much for all the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually looks like the code is fine. Looking at the response is shows that there is an *Object* within the ResultSet.Rows. Try to stringify the result before logging such that the handler looks like this:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

    athena.getQueryResults({
        QueryExecutionId: "a1b2c3d4-5678-90ab-cdef-EXAMPLE11111"
        },function(err,data){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log("Body: ", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    });
}
```